# Can't adjust USB-C audio master volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, usb-c

I've recently switched to using [this USB-C cable](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/295484537759) for my Audio Technica headphones. I'm able to adjust the master fine when I use it on my Android phone, but in KDE and PAVUcontrol any reduction in volume causes it to mute.

[image: PAVUcontrol screenie]

My headphones are the one labelled 'UACDemoV1.0 Analogue Stereo'. Audio only plays when it is at 99% or 100%, although I am able to individually reduce the audio for each application using the playback tab. Strangely enough I'm able to change the master volume in ALSAMixer without this issue.